# How refs/heads/(nobranch) appeared on remote?

Tags: git

When giving maintenance on a Git repository here at work I surprisingly found a `refs/heads/(nobranch)`.

When does Git behave in that way? In other words, how the individual did that?

I've being in a *no branch* situation before (i.e. when rebasing) but that doesn't create an actual pointer on *refs/head* (I did a quick test).

By the way, this is on our remote (a bare repo).